# Javafx linear-gradient repeat behaviour

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Javafx linear-gradient repeat seems to reflect the colours rather than repeat.

I wrote a simple application to show what I see when using linear-gradient with repeat to create a striped pattern in my application on a custom Node (a StackPane). In my application this are added as overlays to a XYChart and their height varies. Using a Rectangle wasn't working well which is why I use a Stackpane and set a style on it rather than creating the LinearGradient programmatically.
The colour list is dynamic and varies in size in the application.
The issue is the way linear-gradient flips the list and reflects the colours on each repeat rather than just repeat.

This link describes a similar issue but just adding in endless stops seemless like a messy solution for my issue, it would be much better to add the colours once and repeat.

[linear gradient repeat on css for javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679530/linear-gradient-repeat-on-css-for-javafx/55497718#55497718)

```
java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            List<Color> colors = Arrays.asList( Color.RED,Color.BLUE,Color.YELLOW,Color.GREEN);

            StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();

            stackPane.setStyle(getLinearGradientStyle(colors));
            root.setCenter(stackPane);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getLinearGradientStyle(List<Color> colors) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 10px 10px, repeat,");
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
            stringBuilder.append("rgb(")
                    .append((int) (colors.get(i).getRed() * 255)).append(",")
                    .append((int) (colors.get(i).getGreen() * 255)).append(",")
                    .append((int) (colors.get(i).getBlue() * 255))
                    .append(")")
                    .append(" ").append(getPercentage(i+1, colors.size()+1) );
            if (i < colors.size() - 1) {
                stringBuilder.append(",");
            }
        }
        stringBuilder.append(");");
        System.out.println("Main.getLinearGradientStyle():"+stringBuilder);
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private String getPercentage(float i, int size) {
        return  (((1.0f / size) * 100 )*i)+ "%";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

}
```

Here's a CSS3 example using repeating-linear-gradient:

https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/repeating-linear-gradient/

scroll down to the following text: will create a striped background, where each linear gradient is a three-stripe gradient, repeated infinitely (this is the example)

My example uses a diagonal pattern which is what I need but the above example shows what I'd like to see in terms of solid repeating colours with out reflection in normal css.

Thanks for any help

Comment: [The bug will be fixed in JavaFX 13](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8222222).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug. If you run the following example (moved the CSS into a file):

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Region region = new Region();
        region.backgroundProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) ->
                System.out.println(nv.getFills().get(0).getFill()));

        Scene scene = new Scene(region, 500, 300);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("Main.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

**Main.css**

```css
.root {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 10px 10px, repeat, red 20%, blue 40%, yellow 60%, green 80%);
}
```

You'll see the following printed out:

```
linear-gradient(from 0.0px 0.0px to 10.0px 10.0px, reflect, 0xff0000ff 0.0%, 0xff0000ff 20.0%, 0x0000ffff 40.0%, 0xffff00ff 60.0%, 0x008000ff 80.0%, 0x008000ff 100.0%)
```

As you can see, despite using "repeat" in the CSS the `LinearGradient` that is created uses "reflect".

There is likely nothing you can do about this bug yourself, but if you don't mind setting the background in code (or probably even FXML) then the following should do what you want:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 10, 10, false, CycleMethod.REPEAT,
                new Stop(0.2, Color.RED),
                new Stop(0.4, Color.BLUE),
                new Stop(0.6, Color.YELLOW),
                new Stop(0.8, Color.GREEN)
        );

        Region region = new Region();
        region.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(gradient, null, null)));

        Scene scene = new Scene(region, 500, 300);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

*You can move the creation of the `LinearGradient` into a method that takes an arbitrary number of `Color`s, just like you're currently doing.*

---

If you're interested, I believe the bug is located in `javafx.css.CssParser` around line `1872` (in JavaFX 12):

```
CycleMethod cycleMethod = CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE;
if ("reflect".equalsIgnoreCase(arg.token.getText())) {
    cycleMethod = CycleMethod.REFLECT;
    prev = arg;
    arg = arg.nextArg;
} else if ("repeat".equalsIgnoreCase(arg.token.getText())) {
    cycleMethod = CycleMethod.REFLECT;
    prev = arg;
    arg = arg.nextArg;
}
```

As you can see, it erroneously sets the `CycleMethod` to `REFLECT` when the text is equal to `"repeat`".

A bug report has been filed: [JDK-8222222](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8222222) (GitHub [#437](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/437)). *Fix version: openjfx13*.

Comment: Hey that's great, thanks for pointing out that bug. I've implemented a version of your suggestion and it works great :) Thank you very much

Comment: It seems this error has been there at least since Java 8. However, it would be good to [file](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues) it, so it can be acknowledged and fixed.

Comment: @JoséPereda As mentioned at the end of my answer, I have already submitted a bug report—just haven't gotten feedback yet. Though I submitted it to the JBS, should I also raise the issue over at GitHub?

Comment: Ideally, you'd file the bug at GitHub once you have the JBS issue approved, with the issue's id. If for any reason you don't get feedback, then go ahead and submit it to GitHub and mention it.

Comment: @JoséPereda Done. Added links to end of answer.